# Is it better to go through stemming or lemmatizing when preprocessing text to apply Latent Dirichlet Allocation?

Tags: r, text-mining, stemming, lemmatization

I am applying Latent Dirichlet Allocation to 230k texts in order to organize the data presented. I'm not sure if it would be better to apply stemming or lemmatizing in the preproessing tokenization function while using text2vec library in R.

I reviewd both outcomes and they are different, even when it's the exact same word. The counts differ most of the times and some words missing in the other.

```
tok_fun <- function(x) {
  tokens <- word_tokenizer(x) 
  textstem::lemmatize_words(tokens)
}
vs
tok_fun <- function(x) {
  tokens <- word_tokenizer(x)
  lapply(tokens, SnowballC::wordStem, language="en")
}
```

Comment: "Better" how? Different analyses produce different results but which one is "better" depends on what problem you are trying to solve exactly. This doesn't appear to be a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you have general questions about statistical methods, you should instead ask your question at [stats.se] or [datascience.se].

Comment: You need to understand what does lammatizing and stemming do. Obviously they will be different because they serve a different purposes.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, this was intentioned as a homework question. All I'm trying to do is organizing those files.